# 21 women can complete the work in 20 days by working 10 hours a day. How long will 21 men complete the work by working 8 hours a day if 3 men=5 women?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Twenty one women can complete a piece of work in 20 days by working 10 hours a day. In how many days 21 men will complete the work by working 8 hours a day if 3 men work as much as 5 women?

21 women can do--------20*10=200 units of work
21 men can do----------8*x units of work
3M=5W( given)
M=$5/3$W
$21*8*x=5/3*20*100$
It does not give me the right answer

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: I have edited the question...see what I have tried @Bram28

Comment: HINT: How many days will it take 21 *women* to do the work if they work 8 hours a day instead of 10?

Comment: Didn't understand @Bram28

Comment: I mean instead of men, take those same 21 women who normally work 10 hours a day.  If they now work 8 hours a day, how long will it take them to do the job?

Comment: The RHS is messed up, $5$ women have the capacity to work as much as $3$ men, so you should factor it by $3/5$, and so it's $21 \times 3/5 \times 200$.

Comment: Hey, @UmashankarSasikumar I have understood this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the same number of men as women here. If three men do as much work as 5 women, then it will take the men $\frac{3}{5}$ as much time. It takes the women, as you calculuated, 200 hours. Thus, it will take the men $3\cdot 200/5=120$ hours. At 8 hours per day, it will take the men $120/8=15$ days to finish.

Comment: 3M can do as much work as 5 women...so it should be M=3/5W right? From where did you get 300? @MathTrain

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by M and W, but if M is the amount of work done my a man in unit time and W is the amount of work done by a woman in that same time, then 3M=5W, so M=5/3W.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly what you said @MathTrain. I am asking how did you get 300?

Comment: My apologies, that is a typo and should say 200. I have changed it.

Comment: No worries, cheers! You made me realise my stupid mistake @MathTrain